# My feenix nascita mouse isn't moving my cursor. Ubuntu version appears to not matter. How do I debug this, and get the mouse working?

Tags: usb, mouse

I had 13.04, upgraded to 13.10, and did a fresh install of 13.10, no luck. Any ideas?
Just tail -f'd my syslog and plugged in the mouse. here is what I got:

```
Oct 26 16:15:50 Orithyia kernel: [83369.618365] usb 1-1.5.2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
Oct 26 16:15:50 Orithyia kernel: [83369.718913] usb 1-1.5.2: New USB device found, idVendor=04d9, idProduct=a081
Oct 26 16:15:50 Orithyia kernel: [83369.718919] usb 1-1.5.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Oct 26 16:15:50 Orithyia kernel: [83369.718921] usb 1-1.5.2: Product: USB Gaming Mouse
Oct 26 16:15:50 Orithyia kernel: [83369.718924] usb 1-1.5.2: Manufacturer: Holtek
Oct 26 16:15:50 Orithyia kernel: [83369.722486] input: Holtek USB Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.2/1-1.5.2:1.0/input/input13
Oct 26 16:15:50 Orithyia kernel: [83369.722786] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A081.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Holtek USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.2/input0
Oct 26 16:15:50 Orithyia kernel: [83369.729362] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A081.0005: usage index exceeded
Oct 26 16:15:50 Orithyia kernel: [83369.729366] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A081.0005: item 0 2 2 2 parsing failed
Oct 26 16:15:50 Orithyia kernel: [83369.729379] hid-generic: probe of 0003:04D9:A081.0005 failed with error -22
Oct 26 16:15:50 Orithyia kernel: [83369.731759] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A081.0006: hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Device [Holtek USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.2/input2
Oct 26 16:15:50 Orithyia mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.2"
Oct 26 16:15:50 Orithyia mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
```

So, I see it did see it is a mouse... but the cursor doesn't move when I move the mouse. Not sure where to debug from here.

**EDIT:**

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Laser Mouse                  id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ daskeyboard                               id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ daskeyboard                               id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Holtek USB Gaming Mouse                   id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

kinda funny that a mouse is under the keyboard category. Probably related to whatever problem this is.

Comment: "USB HID v1.10 Keyboard" I see a probable problem there. What's the output of `xinput`? Also, did it work in a Live CD? or a version older, like 12.04.3?

Comment: just added that output.  
It didn't work in 12.10. Didn't try 12.04.  
It doesn't work in a liveCD/USB environment.

Comment: This seems like a kernel bug, it seems likely because of the hard-to-find nature of the hardware that the driver might need work. My recommendation is to try your luck with a report at bugzilla.kernel.org and include the results of the outputs in your question, as well as `lsusb`. In your report, also report your finding with a [fresher kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).

Comment: Aight. I'll try that. Do I really need a new kernel? 13.10 just upgraded the kernal. `uname -a`: `Linux Orithyia 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
`

Comment: The kernel guys will ask you to anyway; it helps to be absolutely certain it hasn't been fixed yet. You just have to download the *x86_64 files and *all file, `cd` to the directory they're in, and do `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`. Once finished testing, remove them with `apt` as you would any other kernel. These kernels are upstream kernels that represent the latest Ubuntu kernel versions as opposed to the version that's in the Ubuntu archives people download with `apt`.

Comment: Does it work on Windows? I mean, are you sure the fault lies with the OS and not the device?

Comment: It does work on Windows, yeah. Windows 7 Pro, and 8 Pro.

Comment: Just see whether you can use a friend's Mouse (of a popular brand/make please) on it fine. If you can, check out my answer below. Good luck. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Upgrading the Kernel to 3.11.7**

The most probable reason seems to be that there's no driver for this particular piece of hardware due to it being a not-so-popular brand. Upgrading to a new Kernel (3.11) that comes with 13.10 Saucy may solve this.

1. Run commands below one by one to download DEBs for Kernel 3.11.7 (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the Terminal):

   For 32 bit systems:

   ```
   wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.7-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.7-031107-generic_3.11.7-031107.201311040853_i386.deb
   wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.7-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.7-031107_3.11.7-031107.201311040853_all.deb
   wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.7-saucy/linux-image-3.11.7-031107-generic_3.11.7-031107.201311040853_i386.deb
   ```

   For 64 bit systems:

   ```
   wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.7-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.7-031107-generic_3.11.7-031107.201311040853_amd64.deb
   wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.7-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.7-031107_3.11.7-031107.201311040853_all.deb
   wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.7-saucy/linux-image-3.11.7-031107-generic_3.11.7-031107.201311040853_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Both 32 bit & 64 bit install them via:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.11.7-*.deb linux-image-3.11.7-*.deb
   ```

   Once done, restart your computer.

---

**2. Reporting a Bug**

If upgrading the Kernel doesn't solve it, you better report a bug giving as many details of your problem as possible [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/).

---

**3. Get a new Mouse**

You should report the bug, but it may take some time before it's patched (or it may be fixed in a couple of days too). Although I hate to give this advice (for it's not fit for developers to talk such), but these day Mice are dirt-cheap; ones from likes of Microsoft & Logitech cost INR 300-350 (USD 4.8-5.6 today) here in India. Just get a simple Logitech one if you can.

P.S. I know Nascita is a pretty good Gaming mouse, but you don't need it for that purpose on Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks. :-)
You're right, a gaming mouse on ubuntu is a little overkill. I actually can't really play computer games anymore due to my carpel tunnels being dumb. But the mouse is THE most comfortable thing I've ever held. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the kernel itself, and its not just mouse or keyboard, but all USB devices (bluetooth, wlan, ...)

The solution is to upgrade to a newer kernel (newer then 3.11.0) which at this moment is not available directly.

Follow the directions at

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/install-upgrade-kernel-3-11-ubuntu-mint/

to upgrade your kernel to 3.11.7 This solved all my USB related problems at least :)

Giray

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you really need a new kernel. The mouse exceed `HID_MAX_USAGES` as a lot of other `Holtek` based devices. Support have been added in kernel 3.11.5 and higher. If you for some reason wanna stick to your current kernel and add support for the device manually. Have a look at [this patch.](http://linux-kernel.2935.n7.nabble.com/PATCH-HID-Added-Holtek-USB-ID-04d9-a081-SHARKOON-DarkGlider-Gaming-mouse-td728911.html)

Comment: thanks for explaining the reasoning for why it doesn't work with my kernel. I like knowing details like this :-)